# Create array from input fields

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have multiple fields name like

```
<input type="text" name="question[1]" value="Yes" />
<input type="text" name="question[2]" value="No" />
<input type="text" name="question[3]" value="Other" />
```

Many more like that. I want to create array object like below

```
 const question= [{

        question: 1,
        answer: "Yes",
    },{
         question: 2,
         answer: "No",
      },
      {
         question: 3,
        answer: "Yes",
      }
    ];
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -1):

take a look at the form submit event attribute. On a submit event, you can grab all the inputs values from a callback within, and create an array of objects.

```js
const onSubmit = (e) => {
e.preventDefault()
const data = new FormData(e.currentTarget)
const fieldValues = Object.fromEntries(data.entries());
const newValues = []
for([key, value] of Object.entries(fieldValues)) newValues.push({question: key, answer: value})
console.log(newValues)
}
```

```css
form {
  display:flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
input{
  width:100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<form onsubmit="onSubmit(event)">

<input name="password1" />
<input name="password2" />
<input name="password3" />
<button type="submit"> Submit </button>
</form>
```

In React, this would look like this:

```
const Form = () => {
    const onSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        const data = new FormData(e.currentTarget)
        const fieldValues = Object.fromEntries(data.entries());
        const newValues = []
        for([key, value] of Object.entries(fieldValues)) 
        newValues.push({question: key, answer: value})
        //do what you need with the array object, like store it,etc
        console.log(newValues)
    }
    return(
      <form onSubmit={onSubmit}>
         <input name="password1" />
         <input name="password2" />
         <input name="password3" />
         <button type="submit"> Submit </button>
      </form>
    )
}
```

If you want to create the array object prior to form submission, this looks different in react. You would need to generate the inputs based on a quasi created object, like so.

```
const Form = () => {
  //array of object can be accessed here
  const [data, setData] = useState([
    { question: 1, answer: "" },
    { question: 2, answer: "" },
    { question: 3, answer: "" },
  ]);
  const onChange = (e) => {
    const idx = e.currentTarget.dataset["idx"];
    const value = e.currentTarget.value;
    const newData = [...data];
    newData[idx].answer = value;
    setData(newData);
  };
  return (
    <form>
      {data.map((el, idx) => (
        <input
          onChange = {onChange}
          id={el.question}
          value={el.answer}
          name={el.question}
          data-idx={idx}
        />
      ))}
    </form>
  );
};
```